# Download bing image search results using python (custom url)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, bing

I want to download bing search images using python code.

**Example URL:** https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=sketch%2520using%20iphone%2520students

My python code generates an url of bing search as shown in example. Next step, is to download all images shown in that link on my local desktop.

In my project i am generating some words in python and my code generates bing image search URL. All i need is to download images shown on that search page using python.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used beautiful soup, urllib but unable to get all images from webpage (Bing image search page) @which_part

Answer (score 2):

To download an image, you need to make a request to the image URL that ends with `.png`, `.jpg` etc.

But Bing provides a `"m"` attribute inside the `<a>` element that stores needed data in the [`JSON format`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) from which you can parse the image URL that is stored in the `"murl"` key and download it afterward.

[image]

To download all images locally to your computer, you can use 2 methods:

```py
# bs4

for index, url in enumerate(soup.select(".iusc"), start=1):
    img_url = json.loads(url["m"])["murl"]
    image = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    query = query.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    
    if image.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"images/{query}_image_{index}.jpg", 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image.content)
```

```py
# urllib

for index, url in enumerate(soup.select(".iusc"), start=1):
    img_url = json.loads(url["m"])["murl"]
    query = query.lower().replace(" ", "_")

    opener = req.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders=[("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36")]
    req.install_opener(opener)
    req.urlretrieve(img_url, f"images/{query}_image_{index}.jpg")
```

In the first case, you can use [context manager `with open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to load the image locally. In the second case, you can use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) of the [`urllib.request` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

Also, make sure you're using [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) to act as a "real" user visit. Because default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and websites understand that it's most likely a script that sends a request. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

Note: An error might occur with the `urllib.request.urlretrieve` method where some of the request has got a captcha or something else that returns an unsuccessful [`status code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The biggest problem is it's hard to test for response code while `requests` provide a [`status_code`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) method to test it.

---

Code and [full example in online IDE](https://replit.com/@chukhraiartur/download-bing-image-search-results-using-python-custom-url#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json

query = "sketch using iphone students"

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": query,
    "first": 1
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

for index, url in enumerate(soup.select(".iusc"), start=1):
    img_url = json.loads(url["m"])["murl"]
    image = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    query = query.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    
    if image.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"images/{query}_image_{index}.jpg", 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image.content)
```

---

Using [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json
import urllib.request as req

query = "sketch using iphone students"

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": query,
    "first": 1
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

for index, url in enumerate(soup.select(".iusc"), start=1):
    img_url = json.loads(url["m"])["murl"]
    query = query.lower().replace(" ", "_")

    opener = req.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders=[("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36")]
    req.install_opener(opener)
    req.urlretrieve(img_url, f"images/{query}_image_{index}.jpg")
```

---

Output:

[image: Demonstration of uploading files to a folder]

Answer (score 0):

edit your code to find the designated image url and then use this code

## use urllib.request

```
import urllib.request as req

    imgurl ="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/hqdefault.jpg"

    req.urlretrieve(imgurl, "image_name.jpg")
```

Comment: But how can i get name of a specific image in google search ? Is there any way to download all images from a webpage?

Comment: Not working! It gives an Error  'with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ]'